# Next.js, how to submit a form to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

(*Next.js*) I have a GET form on one page. I want to submit it to another page. I know I can set the `action` property to the other page. That works. However, it does a page reload instead of just rendering the new page; the same as would happen if you had a link on the page without wrapping it in a `Link` component.

I could catch the submit event, build a query, and push it onto the router. But that seems like a lot of extra work for something I assume has already been figured out.

Any ideas how to do this without reinventing the wheel?

```html
<form method='get' action='/search'>
  <input name='q' placeholder='Search' arial-label='Search' />
</form>
```

Comment: I could catch the submit event, build a query, and push it onto the router. <- i think is the only solution

Comment: @Nico, that appears to be the case. It just seems like something that should have been solved already. I know it's not that complicated, but I'm surprised it isn't built in, like `Link`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ended up catching the submit event and pushing a URL onto the router.

```js
import {useState} from 'react'
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const preventDefault = f => e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  f(e)
}

export default ({action = '/search'}) => {
   const router = useRouter()
   const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

   const handleParam = setValue => e => setValue(e.target.value)

   const handleSubmit = preventDefault(() => {
     router.push({
       pathname: action,
       query: {q: query},
     })
   })

   return (
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <input
         type='text'
         name='q'
         value={query}
         onChange={handleParam(setQuery)}
         placeholder='Search'
         aria-label='Search'
       />
     </form>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the Next.js' [routing system](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction#linking-between-pages) and [Router API](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-api):

> The Next.js router allows you to do client-side route transitions between pages, similarly to a single-page application. A special React component called **Link** is provided to do this client-side route transition.
>
> **Router.push** also handles client-side transitions, and this method is useful for cases where next/link is not enough.

So it seems that you can only perform client-side transitions by using any of those two ways.

Using the form above will trigger a behavior as described by [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) for a form submission, as none of the above rules applies:

> ...The server then responds, generally handling the data and loading the URL defined by the **action** attribute, **causing a new page load** (or a refresh of the existing page, if the action points to the same page).

I also found another [reference](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9780) close to your question in Next.js' issues board, where the [preferred method](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9780#issuecomment-567316865) to follow, was the one you've also described as a solution.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Though you've basically just described the options I originally outlined in my question.